# iOS Firebase Cloud Messaging Conflicting With Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am writing a iOS and Android application that is supposed to notify users through the FCM API yet there seems to be a catch-22 within the firebase API that involves both platforms:

On Android, to handle new notifications using a custom implementation of FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived(), one must create a DATA only message server-side. E.g: `{ "data": {"param": "foo"  },"to" : "/topics/bar"}`.  The moment a "notification" field is included in the json, the custom implementation will not be called when the app is in the background.  This would be ok but...

On iOS, if the "notification" field is not included in the message, the message just isn't received when the app is in the background which is unacceptable.

Thus, to receive background notification on iOS, you need to add the "notification" field, but adding this field makes the Android apps display bogus, non-customizable notifications when in the background!

I hope there is something that I am missing in the documentation.  I would like to know how others have overcome this problem and whether it would be wise to stick with FCM for iOS or ditch it for something else.

Comment: that is not true, you add the content available flag into the ios payload and override the remote notifications method in your app delegate. then that gets called and you manually create your notification

Comment: We came across the same issue. Previously, using just the _notification_ field worked, but apparently some recent change in Android behaviour has caused this to need to use the _data_ field. 

We fixed this by having our server send different payloads to iOS and android devices - our Android dev mentioned others had brought up the same issue in some Firebase forum?